# MySQL: One statement in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help :( I have table like this...

```sql
ID|code|item|user|
01|aaaa|1111|0001|
02|bbbb|1111|0001|
03|cccc|1111|0001|
04|dddd|1111|0001|
05|aaaa|1111|0002|
06|eeee|1111|0002|
07|ffff|1111|0001|
```

I'm user 0002 and I know my item numer (for example 1111). I don't know other users, ids and other codes, but i have to get only 02,03,04,07 results (for this example). Any sinle and duplicated rows (for code column) with user 002 should be ignored... if you know what i mean. Any ideas how? :(

Comment: It's a little hard to decrypt your message, but is this the pattern you are looking for: `user <> :given_user AND item = :given_item AND code <>` *any code, which :given_user has under :given_item* ?

Comment: Explain your logic.   Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: This has been tagged with both `mysql` and `postgresql`, which are two different DB systems. Which one of those is appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a subquery filter

```
select *
    from myTable
    where code not in (
        select code
            from myTable
            where user = '0002'
    )
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
select ID
from myTable
where  user <> '0002'
group by ID, code
having count(code) = 1
```

Comment: This query display 1,2,3,4 and 7 rows. But row 1 should be displayed because "code" column is duplicated with row number 5. That is the problem...

Comment: (...) But row 1 should NOT displayed because "code" column is duplicated with row number 5. (...)

Comment: Updated with distinct... Try to read some tutorial instead of posting the questions

Comment: I tired to do it before but still this query shows rows: 01,02,03,04,07 . Row number 01 should not be displayed.

Comment: Updated again .